# Remove characters in Googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to remove the first and last characters of a text in a cell. I know how to remove just the first or the last with formulas such as =LEFT(A27, LEN(A27)-1) but i want to combine two formulas at the same time for first and last character or maybe there is a formula that I'm not aware of which removes both (first and last characters) at the same time.

I know about Power Tool but i want to avoid using this tool and I'm trying to realize this simply by formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `REGEXREPLACE()` function:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A27, "^.|.$", "")
```

The regular expression used here matches:

- `^.` the first character after the start of the string
- `|` OR
- `.$` the last character of the string

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you elaborate a little more so i can understand how this works. Thank you so much

Comment: Check the updated answer for a brief explanation.  If you're very new to regex, consider working through a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

better not to use this but it works too:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A27, LEN(A27)-1), LEN(LEFT(A27, LEN(A27)-1))-1)
```

[image]

```
=LAMBDA(x, RIGHT(LEFT(A27, x), LEN(LEFT(A27, x))-1))(LEN(A27)-1)
```

[image]

```
=LAMBDA(x, LAMBDA(y, RIGHT(y, LEN(y)-1))(LEFT(A27, x)))(LEN(A27)-1)
```

[image]

```
=LAMBDA(x, RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-1))(LEFT(A27, LEN(A27)-1))
```

[image]